# Symfony2 dependency Injection : performances impact

Tags: performance, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm refactoring one of my controller to make it a service and I want to know if there is a performance impact to not inject whole service container into my controller.

Is this is more efficient :

```
innova.path.controller:
    class: %innova.controller.path.class%
    arguments:
       entityManager:   @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
       session:         @session
       securityContext: @security.context
       router:          @router
       translator:      @translator
       pathManager:     @innova.manager.path_manager
    calls:
       - [setRequest, ["@?request="]]
    scope: request
```

than this, for example ?

```
innova.path.controller:
    class: %innova.controller.path.class%
    arguments: [@service_container]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official documentation explicitly tell to not inject whole DIC into a Controller (thanks @NHG for link).

Section [How to work with scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) :

> Injecting the whole container into a service is generally not a good
>   idea (only inject what you need).

But in section [Service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) :

> When you ask for the my_mailer service from the container, the
>   container constructs the object and returns it. This is another major
>   advantage of using the service container. Namely, a service is never
>   constructed until it's needed. If you define a service and never use
>   it on a request, the service is never created. This saves memory and
>   increases the speed of your application. This also means that there's
>   very little or no performance hit for defining lots of services.
>   Services that are never used are never constructed.

So injecting the whole DIC to controller will not have performances impact because only the services used in controller are instanciated.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using controllers as service is injecting only necessery services. Standard controller extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` which extending `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware`. So, injecting whole container is makes no sense...

Generally, injecting less service is more efficient than injecting whole container.
Additionally you should familiarize with [base Symfony2 Controller class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php).

Comment: Injecting only necessary services is not the only advantage : I want to use services to easily be able to replace controller if needed by replacing the parameter which defines the controller class in the config. I can't figure out how it can be more efficient to inject only needed services because I seemed to have read (maybe I'm wrong) services use `Singleton pattern` and are instanciated only first time you need it. So not required services are not loaded. Why do you talk about `Controller` class ? It has nothing to do with this and is only interesting when you're newbie in symfony.

Comment: I was writing about `Controller` class because I wanted to show you what is the difference between standard Controller and controller defined as service - simple PHP class. Main difference is extending `ContainerAware` (give access to DIC). Of course you have right - when you defined Controller as service you can simple change controller class. Regarding to `Singleton pattern` you are wrong. There is 2 scopes: `container`, `prototype` (and extra `request`) for services. Please look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Comment: I have make an answer with information found from your link and another doc section. It appears that even if the injection of the whole DIC is not recommended, there is no real difference in performance. Unless if there are background processes in `ServiceContainer` other than instanciate requested services that I don't know.